# listview setOnItemClickListener not working on some items after refreshing the list items or leaving activity open for some time

Tags: android, listview

In my activity, list view having multiple items populated, based on canceled, approved or rejected i am differentiating them.

`list.setOnItemClickListener` on every items works perfectly till i am refreshing the list(refresh method that updates the list items) items by refresh button.
After refreshing or leaving the `Activity` idle for some minutes `onClick` event on approved items doesn't seem to be working and i am unable to figure out the reason behind it.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Don't you think it might be easier for someone to help you, if they could see your code?

Comment: Yes it will help for sure.. But unfortunately due to some limitation with sharing of those codes i can't. If someone have common advice on this please share.. it may help... thanks in advance..!!